# CV2 cap.set(1,idx); cap.read(), Does it Read Frame idx or Frame idx+1

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

In CV2 will this chunk of code read the frame for the given frame number or the next frame?

```
desiredFrames = [3,5,7,n]
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("somefile")

for idx in desiredFrames:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES,idx);
    cap.read() #Does it Read Frame idx or Frame idx+1
```

So will I get frames [3,5,7,n]
Or frames [4,6,8,n+1]

Thanks.

Comment: The [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d15/group__videoio__flags__base.html#gaeb8dd9c89c10a5c63c139bf7c4f5704d) says "0-based index of the frame to be decoded/captured next". The index of the first frame in the video file is `0`. So index `3` is the 4'th frame.

Comment: Thanks but I know that it is 0 indexed. My question is does cap.set(1,idx); go to frame i and then when I call cap.read() it reads i+1? In other words if I tell it to page to frame 5 and then do the read does it page one from 5 and return frame 6 or does cap.read read and then page?

Comment: I have posted a code sample that proves that the frames are `[3,5,7,n]`... Please execute the code sample in your machine (I want to make sure that the sample code is working, especially the parts related to FFmpeg). In case you are using Windows, download FFmpeg from [here](https://www.gyan.dev/ffmpeg/builds/packages/ffmpeg-4.4.1-full_build.7z). And place `ffmpeg.exe` in the same folder as the Python script.

Comment: ***please use `CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES`*** instead of the magic number `1`. and delete all bookmarks to whatever horrible guide you were following that taught you to use `1`.

Comment: Ok, I fixed up the cap.set(1,...) issue. If possible what is your rationale for one over the other? Yea I will agree there are a lot of horrible guides any advice on video management in python resources for us noobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to get frames `[3, 5, 7, n]` (and the index of the first frame in the video file is `0`).

We may prove it by a simple test.
Start by building synthetic pattern video file using [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) CLI.
Each frame (of the pattern) includes a frame counter that starts counting from zero.

For using FFmpeg within python, the FFmpeg executable should be in the execution path (we may also use full path).

Building the sample file:

```
sp.run(shlex.split('ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=128x72:rate=1:duration=10 somefile.mp4'))
```

Converting the MP4 video frames into sequence of PNG images:

```
sp.run(shlex.split('ffmpeg -i somefile.mp4 somefile_frame%03d.png'))
```

Here are the first 5 frames as images (we can see that each frame has a frame counter starting from 0):
[image] [image] [image] [image] [image]

---

Testing `desiredFrames = [3, 5, 7]`:

Here is a "self contained" code sample that builds the input video file, seek to frames 3, 5, 7, show the frames and save to PNG images:

```
import cv2
import subprocess as sp
import shlex

# Build sample video file for testing (suing FFmpeg CLI).
# The test pattern includes a frame counter that start from 0.
sp.run(shlex.split('ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=128x72:rate=1:duration=10 somefile.mp4'))
sp.run(shlex.split('ffmpeg -i somefile.mp4 somefile_frame%03d.png'))

desiredFrames = [3, 5, 7]

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("somefile.mp4")

for idx in desiredFrames:
    cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, idx);
    _, frame = cap.read()  # Does it Read Frame idx or Frame idx+1?

    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)  # Show the frame for testing
    cv2.waitKey(1000)

    cv2.imwrite(f'frame{idx}.png', frame)  # Save the frame t PNG file for testing

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Output video frames:
[image] [image] [image]

As you can see, the captured frames are `3`, `5` and `7`.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Neat trick with shlex and sp.